# How to use design pattern if I have parameter to pass to the product class generater?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am relatively new to the design pattern, and it seems to me that the design pattern is most difficult part and the top level to the whole software design (please correct me if I am wrong).

I have a big class now with several embeded functionalities, and I want to refactor some functionalities into subclasses. But most of these subclasses will use the output from its preceding code output as constructor input. This makes me confused. How should I implement this situation into my design pattern? Or should I avoid this dependency situation?

The following is an example of my class:

```
    public  class Edit 
    {
         private List<Graphic> _listGraphic;
         public Initialization()
         {
             _listGraphic= SomeFunctionHere();
             BatchEdit batchEdit= new BatchEdit(_listGraphic);
          }

     }

     public class BatchEdit
    {

         public BatchEdit(List<Graphic> listGra)
         {
         }
    }
```

Thanks,

Wei

Comment: Take a look at this awesome tutorial which will explain as well as help you to decide on which one to implement.
http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx

Comment: I can't quite tell what you mean ... can you include expand your description or include some code?

Comment: While I second the need for source code, I still would note that there's no such thing as "implementing something into one's design pattern". In fact, "your" design pattern is something you invent, and most design patterns are already here for us.

Comment: I use the term Implement in regards to which Design Patter he would like to use.. not in an Instance scenario.."UTILIZE" is a better term to use

Comment: Thanks, guys, I just added my code example.

Comment: I, for one, can't undestand a thing from your code. Why is it structured like this? Why do you create and instance of `BatchEdit` inside `Edit`? What do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me as if you want to [*delegate*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) some behaviour to other classes, which are usually not "subclasses" (in terms of inheritance).

A delegate may depend on it's caller - you may pass a reference to the caller to the constructor, if the delegate needs use some of it's callers.

Please do not confuse "design" with "design pattern". You develop a *design* for your application that should be build upon common *design patterns*. Design patterns guide to solutions for most common problems.